# What is this "web" icon in iOS battery usage?

Tags: iphone, ios, battery, icon

Does anyone know what this “web” icon is under battery usage in iOS 13.6 ?

[image: Battery usage]

Answer (score 4):

The "Web"-icon in the battery settings are the time, where was used by visiting a website, where you have saved from *safari* as "Add to Home Screen" via the share-button.

So you have *like your own app* on the home screen, but effectively it is only a website that is called about safari. Therefore it is declared as "Web" in the battery settings.

[image]